# Possible to get cleartext password?

Tags: password

I have hosting service hosted on more than 20+ Plesk servers, version 11.
As in the previous versions, the passwords were not encrypted, then if i had to design some tools to manage the hosting accounts, i just picked up the cleartext passwords from the Database. but as now the passwords are encrypted, is there any way i can decrypt the passwords? through API or any other way so that i can integrate my php based hosting management with plesk 11?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code provided by Giulio isn't helpful, here's a Python script that actually works. Requires PyCrypto (python-crypto). Assumes that Plesk secret key is stored at `/etc/psa/private/secret_key`. Just run it and pass in encrypted passwords as arguments:

```
./deplesk.py '$AES-128-CBC$T82uDt6NSdytfhjQaOIKGg==$CMJ6FIdAD8zJ0PgwQ3DosA=='
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = open('/etc/psa/private/secret_key', 'rb').read()

for pw in sys.argv[1:]:
    lead, typ, iv, ct = pw.split('$')
    iv = base64.b64decode(iv)
    ct = base64.b64decode(ct)
    assert typ == 'AES-128-CBC'
    plain = AES.new(key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv).decrypt(ct).rstrip(b'\0')
    print(plain.decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I can confirm this works with Plesk 11.5

Comment: Don't forget single quotes around passsword otherwise you'll get a "ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack"

Comment: Not always working btw... with this password $AES-128-CBC$05M0XNpwbg6UzMV7nSj2qw==$d6vcsC92Ly2dlGhXS0372w== or this password $AES-128-CBC$KEKiihkO0Kjm+Nc+3BthBQ==$R8MJan9e1KLzTL6+FsCUxg== you'll get a ValueError: need more than 1 values to unpack"

Comment: the code above does not appear to work.

Answer (score 12):

Why not just figure out what hashing algorithm Plesk uses, and replicate that functionality in your PHP application?  You don't need the un-ecrypted version of a password to authenticated against it, and you never really want to store a password in the clear, or with a reversible encryption.

Comment: Agreed. It is a *BAD* idea to store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: Thirded, you should be working with hashes of the passwords rather than trying to decrypt passwords and hack something together. Going the original route introduces a ton of unnecessary risk.

Comment: Can't really do that when Plesk doesn't hash the passwords, though. They are encrypted with AES-128 instead (Varies by version, I assume) so users can view their service passwords in the control panel. I personally agree with your standpoint, but you'd still need to decrypt the password, hash it and store that first.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, if the program can get the encryption password, yes, you can get back the password in plain text.
**EDIT**: added decryption code.

```
function decrypt_password($pass,$key)
{

$base64encoded_ciphertext = $pass;

$res_non = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), ‘ecb’);

$decrypted = $res_non;
$dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);

$padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
$decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);

return  $decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Password are encrypted with AES-128-CBC cypher . so possible to get password from them?

Comment: Please review my answer, I've posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this written in PHP, so I ported @freebobbytables' version directly over. Works a charm. Tested with PHP 8.0.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php    
<?php    
$passwords = array_slice($argv, 1);    
$key = file_get_contents('/etc/psa/private/secret_key');    
    
foreach($passwords as $password) {    
  list($lead, $type, $iv, $ciphertext) = explode('$', $password);    
  $iv = base64_decode($iv);    
    
  assert($type === 'AES-128-CBC');    
  $plain = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);    
  echo utf8_decode($plain) . PHP_EOL;    
}
```